# Como criar uma função similar à implode, mas com limite máximo de caracteres por elemento

Tags: php, algoritmo

Estou tentando criar uma função que transforme uma array em string com um caractere para dividir, semelhante a função `implode`, mas que respeite um limite máximo de 20 caracteres por partes, por exemplo.

```
$ids = array(456456, 23423, 5674684,345345, 56567);

$result = implode(',', 20, $ids);
```

O resultado seria uma array onde cada elemento tenha no máximo 20 caracteres:

```
['456456,23423,5674684', '345345,56567']
```

Não consigo pensar em uma lógica para criar isso, já que cada elemento na array `$ids` pode ter um tamanho diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex:

```php
<?php

$ids = array(456456, 23423, 5674684,345345, 56567);

preg_match_all("(\d[,\d]{0,19})", implode(",", $ids) , $result);

var_dump($result[0]);
/*array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "456456,23423,5674684"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "345345,56567"
}*/

?>
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/implode#main.php)</sup>

A função de processamento de texto [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) busca em uma string por todas as correspondências de um padrão de uma expressão regular. Depois que a primeira correspondência for encontrada, as pesquisas subsequentes continuarão a partir do final da última correspondência.

Imploda o array `$ids` mantendo as virgulas e busque pelo padrão `(\d[,\d]{0,19})` que pode ser traduzido como busque um grupo de captura iniciado por um dígito seguido por nenhum ou até dezenove caracteres `,` ou digito.

Answer (score 2):

A ideia básica é iterar pelos elementos e para cada um deles você vai concatenando enquanto o tamanho não ultrapassa o limite. Quando ultrapassar, você adiciona no array final e começa outro item:

```php
function implode_limit($glue, $pieces, $max_size) {
    $result = [];
    $current_item = '';
    $glue_size = strlen($glue);
    foreach ($pieces as $item) {
        // ao juntar o $item com $current_item, verifica se passa o tamanho máximo
        if (strlen($current_item) + strlen($item) + ($current_item !== '' ? $glue_size : 0) <= $max_size) {
            // não passa o tamanho, pode juntar
            if ($current_item !== '') {
                $current_item .= $glue;
            }
            $current_item .= $item;
        } else { // passa o tamanho máximo, pega o item atual e adiciona no array
            $result[] = $current_item;
            $current_item = $item; // inicia um novo item
        }
    }
    // não esquecer de adicionar o último
    $result[] = $current_item;
    return $result;
}

$ids = array(456456, 23423, 5674684, 345345, 56567);
print_r(implode_limit(',', $ids, 20));
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 456456,23423,5674684
    [1] => 345345,56567
)
```

---

Não ficou claro o que fazer se um elemento já tiver um tamanho maior que o limite. Por exemplo, se o array for:

```php
$ids = ['123456789012345678901234567890', 123, '123456789012345678901234567890', 456, '123456789012345678901234567890'];
```

Repare que o primeiro, terceiro e último elementos por si só já tem mais que 20 caracteres. O que fazer neste caso? Eles não podem ser juntados com nenhum outro, mas também não podem ser colocados sozinhos no array, pois aí ele teria um elemento maior que o tamanho máximo permitido.

Neste caso uma sugestão seria truncar (pegar apenas os 20 primeiros caracteres):

```php
function implode_limit($glue, $pieces, $max_size) {
    $result = [];
    $current_item = '';
    $glue_size = strlen($glue);
    foreach ($pieces as $item) {
        // se juntar com o próximo, verifica se passa o tamanho máximo
        if (strlen($current_item) + strlen($item) + ($current_item !== '' ? $glue_size : 0) <= $max_size) {
            // não passa o tamanho, pode juntar
            if ($current_item !== '') {
                $current_item .= $glue;
            }
            $current_item .= $item;
        } else { // passa o tamanho, pega o item atual e adiciona no array
            if ($current_item !== '')
                $result[] = substr($current_item, 0, $max_size); // pega os primeiros $max_size caracteres
            $current_item = $item;
        }
    }
    // não esquecer de adicionar o último (pega os primeiros $max_size caracteres)
    $result[] = substr($current_item, 0, $max_size);

    return $result;
}

$ids = ['123456789012345678901234567890', 123, '123456789012345678901234567890', 456, '123456789012345678901234567890'];
print_r(implode_limit(',', $ids, 20));
```

No caso, os elementos que possuem mais que 20 caracteres serão truncados e o resultado será:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 12345678901234567890
    [1] => 123
    [2] => 12345678901234567890
    [3] => 456
    [4] => 12345678901234567890
)
```

Mas claro que fica a seu critério decidir o que fazer. Obviamente que se o array não tiver nenhum elemento com mais de 20 caracteres, nada disso é necessário.

Answer (score 0):

> Não consigo pensar em uma lógica para criar isso.

Uma ideia bem básica, sem utilizar qualquer recurso já existente na linguagem seria de ir concatenando até atingir o limite, utializando dois `for`:

```
<?php

$_arrayFinal = [""];
$ids = [456456, 23423, 5674684, 345345, 56567];
$maximo = 20;

// Para cada "id":
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
    // Convert int para string:
    $ids[$i] = strval($ids[$i]);
    
    // Para cara letra:
    for ($ii = 0; $ii < strlen($ids[$i]); $ii++) {
         $_arrayFinal[count($_arrayFinal) - 1] .= $ids[$i][$ii];
        
        // Adiciona para proximo array, limite foi atingido:
        if (strlen($_arrayFinal[count($_arrayFinal) - 1]) % $maximo == 0) {
            $_arrayFinal[] = ""; 
        }
    }
            
    if ($i != count($ids) - 1) {
        // Adiciona a "," se não for o primeiro caractere:
        if (strlen($_arrayFinal[count($_arrayFinal) - 1]) > 0) {
            $_arrayFinal[count($_arrayFinal) - 1] .= ",";
        }
        // Adiciona para proximo array, limite foi atingido:
        if (strlen($_arrayFinal[count($_arrayFinal) - 1]) % $maximo == 0) {
            $_arrayFinal[] = "";
        }
    }
}


var_dump($_arrayFinal);
```

Resultado:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(20) "456456,23423,5674684" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(12) "345345,56567" }
```

---

Se quiser algo mais prático (note: não uso PHP desde 2017, então pode ser que tenha algo mais prático), pode usar o `mb_str_split` + `implode`:

```
$_arrayFinal = mb_str_split(implode(",", [456456, 23423, 5674684, 345345, 56567]),20,"8bit");

var_dump($_arrayFinal);
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(20) "456456,23423,5674684" [1]=> string(13) ",345345,56567" }
```

Porém, esse resultado pode incluir o `,` no inicio da string.

Comment: Eu editei, para remover o `,`, mas isso faz com que o array tenha 19 digitos, ao invés de 20. Ou seja, fica errado da mesma forma. Então editei novamente, para remover o array_map. Além disso, não está claro o comportamento. E se a virgula for ao final? E se o numero já for maior que o máximo de caracteres (considerando que a entrada já seja string/bigInt...)? Enfim, não ligo mais para down-vote, quase não uso StackOverflow mais.